# SharePoint custom workflow

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, visual-studio-2015, visual

I have a requirement to create a workflow. The requirement is pretty simple but I am quiet new to SharePoint workflows so finding it hell of a task.

- there are three users in a team. Any one can create an item in a list and when he creates it the workflow should send a task to the rest of the two users.
- workflow should not send a task to the author.
- when any one of the users review, the workflow should stop regardless if the other reviewer takes an action later or not.

Please help me out and suggest me something how i can implement this in a visual studio sequential workflow.  I am not looking for the step by step approach but just some valuable sketch of what i will need to do.

Again I would be very thankful if someone takes time out of his/her precious time to assist me.

I forgot to mention that i have to use AD group or a distribution list to assign task. So i dont know if we can loop through the group in designer wf and check if the user is author or not. That is the sole reason for going with VS workflow. If we can loop AD users in designer please provide me the steps or the helpful link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would highly, highly recommend not doing code-based workflows. Instead, investigate SharePoint designer to build workflows. Much easier to build, easier to maintain, etc.

Your workflow could be achieved via a few simple condition statements, or to get a little more flexible, perhaps a string replace on a string with all the emails to get rid of the created by user's email.

Re "review", there is an OOB "start a task process" (in 2013 workflows) as well as an OOB "start an approval process" (in 2010 workflows) that both allow you to configure it so the workflow stops after the first approval/response.

Or, you could use Flow. Flow is a cloud tool, but it can connect to on-prem servers, given a gateway. It also has the ability to do a multi-user approval process that stops after the first response.

Comment: +1 for recommending Designer over VS for workflows.  I'm really not a fan of Designer overall, but workflows are one area where it clearly makes a big difference.  Even something as simple as getting or setting a field value on the current item (one step each in Designer) is multiple steps in VS.

Comment: @Mike2500 did u see my updated question. I have to use AD group or an email list to retrieve the users. So can you please tell me how I can achiev that in vs or designer.

Comment: If you need to do something that is not available oob, then check into creating custom workflow actions. This will be a visual studio solution that gets deployed to the server, and the end result is a an additional action that you can use in the workflow process. Much easier over the long run: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-build-and-deploy-workflow-custom-actions

Comment: Wow i dint know that @Mike2500. Thanks i will give it a try

Comment: @Mike2500 one more question. In designer wf can we stop the workflow and mark it completed if any of the task is completed. Bcoz my requirement is the workflow shud create 2 tasks out of which who ever approves it should complete the workflow

Comment: There is a task process that has that built in (one task, who ever completes it first marks it as completed), or you could set up a parallel process to assign two tasks. That gets trickier, but it is doable.